# Wordpress, add custom button on post type list page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add custom button on top of post type page like this image
[image]

Is there any filter or action I can use to add custom button there?

Thanks

Comment: Also asked  here, with no answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163893/how-do-i-add-a-custom-button-to-my-edit-list-edit-phppost-type-beside

Comment: thanks @enigma for adding that up.. been 6 months no one has answered it yet..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a way to get it done but I am not very happy with this procedure. Please add your answer if you find better way. Mean while, this might be of help.

```
add_action('admin_head-edit.php','addCustomImportButton');
```

I only need this on edit page, so I am using `admin_head-edit.php` action, but you can use `admin_head` or some other (not very specific requirement)

```
/**
 * Adds "Import" button on module list page
 */
public function addCustomImportButton()
{
    global $current_screen;

    // Not our post type, exit earlier
    // You can remove this if condition if you don't have any specific post type to restrict to. 
    if ('module' != $current_screen->post_type) {
        return;
    }

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($)
            {
                jQuery(jQuery(".wrap h2")[0]).append("<a  id='doc_popup' class='add-new-h2'>Import</a>");
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Does not work anymore, because of HTML change. (jQuery adds element into invisible area)

Comment: since there is STILL no better alternative, the JS should be changed to:
`<script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function () {
                        jQuery('hr.wp-header-end').before("<a id='doc_popup' class='add-new-h2'>Import</a>");
                    });
                </script>`

Answer (score 11):

Digging into WordPress core code i did not find any hook or any filter for that buttonm you can also see that code from line no [281](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/edit.php#L281) to line number [288](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/edit.php#L288) . But you can add your button [here](https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/200857/C2dlCczrAxN4cpQWseOkpkNTw9x14obQ/) according to this [filter](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/views_%7B$this-%3Escreen-%3Eid%7D).

```
add_filter('views_edit-post','my_filter');
add_filter('views_edit-page','my_filter');

function my_filter($views){
    $views['import'] = '<a href="#" class="primary">Import</a>';
    return $views;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the class WP_Lists_table (and you should) then this is the right way to do it:

```
add_action('manage_posts_extra_tablenav', 'add_extra_button');
function add_extra_button($where)
{
    global $post_type_object;
    if ($post_type_object->name === 'shop_order') {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is sadly still the only one that works.

But as the admin heading changed since it was answered, the correct script should now be :

```
jQuery(jQuery(".wrap .page-title-action")[0]).after('<a href="#" class="page-title-action">Import</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no hook called after showing the "Add New" button.
The closest possible place to add anything without using javascript is **below** the title and "Add new" like this:

[image]

In my example I added a button to my custom post type "Event" using the hook "edit_form_top":

```
add_action('edit_form_top', 'add_custom_button');

function add_custom_button($id){
    if ($post->post_type != 'event') return false;
    echo('<button>Custom button</button>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Touqeer Shafi got me in the right direction, I needed to add a button at the top of my table view for a custom post type (book), I only had to change the post part in the `views_edit-post` to make it work:

```
add_action('views_edit-book', function($id) {
      echo('<a href="/post-new.php?post_type=book" class="page-title-action">Another new book</a>');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2022 with WP 5.9.1, I combined answers from Geza Gog and Tameroski, and it works great:

```php
add_action('edit_form_top', 'my_import_button');
function my_import_button(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($)
        {
            jQuery(jQuery(".wrap .page-title-action")[0]).after('<a href="#" class="page-title-action">Import</a>');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```